# How to input words in for loops comprehension list

Tags: list, for-loop, input, list-comprehension

I would like to get the following for loops in comphrension list if that's possible.

```
for i in range(number_of_word):
    word = input()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
words = [input() for i in range(number_of_word)]
```

Here you get a list `words` with all the values inputted by the user.